# How to get dynamic dropdown data in select2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

In rails 4.0, I am using select2(bootstrap) plugin. I want to generate dynamic data in auto-completion list but data is not loading in the list.
If i used below code, i will get an error like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toUpperCase' of undefined".

```
 $('#DIV_NAME').select2({
  placeholder: "Search for a names",
  multiple: true,
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  ajax: { 
    url: "autocomplete/names",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (term) {
      return { q: term };
   },
    results: function (data) {
      return {results: data};
    }
   }
 });
```

Code reference, http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#multi

From the above link, i have used 2 js files called select2.js, select2.min.js

In controller side,

```
def names
 @query = params[:q]
 @name_list = Keyword.where("value LIKE '%#{@query}%' AND category = 'Name'").limit(15)
 @names = @name_list.collect(&:value)
 @ids = @name_list.collect(&:id)
 @id_name_pairs = Hash[@ids.zip(@names)]

 @values = []
 @id_name_pairs.each_pair do |k, v|
   hash = {}
   hash["id"] = k
   hash["value"] = v
   @values.push(hash)
 end

 respond_to do |format|
   format.html{}
   format.js {
     render :json => @values
   }
 end

end
```

Please help me to solve this select2 issue.

Comment: Wait, are you using select2.js and select2.min.js simultaneously? I assume they both represent the same library/code, in which case you should just use one of them.

Comment: Yep, was just going to ask the same question

Comment: I have tried it by adding only select2.js file then i got the same error. Later i have added select2.min.js file.

Comment: You really just need one of the files because they basically just do the same thing. A .min version of a JS file means it is compressed. You can even uncompress them with sites like http://jsbeautifier.org/ -- Compression just removes all the "humanized" formatting which you put into script (comments, long form variable names, etc), to create a truly streamlined version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your controller.  You are assigning the key name "value" in the values hash for the json response, if you aren't doing custom formatting instead assign "text".

Its in the docs:

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#data_array

smething like this:

```
@id_name_pairs.each_pair do |k, v|
  hash = {}
  hash["id"] = k
  hash["text"] = v
  @values.push(hash)
end
```